# Index-Match Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have two worksheets (sheet 1 and sheet 2)
Sheet 1 contains column A of numbers associated with Column B) - Think company company ID numbers in A, and Company names in B.

Sheet 2 has another group of Column A ID Numbers associated with column B company names in that Sheet) - This group used similar Company names, but used a different company ID numbering system

I want to compare sheet 1 to sheet 2.  Where sheet 1 name matches a name in sheet 2, I want to add a new column so that I see the company ID number from Sheet 1.

I have tried several examples found, but I am not getting any results.

Thank you, Bob

Comment: Please show what you have tried.  It gives us more insight into your problem

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want

```
=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A, MATCH(B1,Sheet1!B:B,0))=A1, "same", INDEX(Sheet1!A:A, MATCH(B1,Sheet1!B:B,0))), "no match")
```

Put that into `Sheet2!C1` and drag/fill down. 
(If you have header row(s), adjust the row numbers accordingly.)

- `MATCH(B1,Sheet1!B:B,0)` takes the company name
  from the current row on Sheet2 (`B1`),
  and looks for it among the company names on Sheet1 (`Sheet1!B:B`). 
  This returns either an index (location) or an error.
- `INDEX(Sheet1!A:A, (the above))` fetches the ID number
  from Sheet1 that corresponds to the index number returned by `MATCH`. 
  If `MATCH` returned an error, this will also.
- Then we compare the ID number from Sheet1
  with the ID number from Sheet2 (`A1`).
  If they are equal, display `same`,
  otherwise display the ID number from Sheet1.
- If `MATCH` returned an error,
  then everything that follows from it is an error. 
  In that case, display `no match`.

I put in the `same` and `no match` strings
for clarity / illustration purposes. 
If you don’t want them, and want to display blanks,
just replace them with empty strings (`""`).

#### Example:

Sheet1:
[image: Sheet1]

Sheet2:
[image: Sheet2]

Notes:

- The names must match *exactly*.
- This does not detect names that are present on Sheet1 but not Sheet2
  (like “Buy More” and “Slate Rock and Gravel Company”).